# how to replace a value with another array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need help to replace a value with another array in js. As you can see in this picture, I would like to have "+" instead of "plus" and I don't know how to do it.

[image: picture]

Any idea?
tk

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I got your intentions right and you try to do something with calculations. I would suggest this approach.

Save the symbols you need in order to convert them in the array later, use `map` over your array, map returns a new array, going over each element and if `signs` has a key that it finds in the array it replaces it with the value corresponding to this key which is the symbol itself.

```
const signs = {
    'plus': '+',
    'minus': '-',
    'multiply': '*',
    'divide': '/'
};

const arr = ['3', 'plus', '3'];

const convertedArr = arr.map((elem) => {
    if (signs[elem]) {
      return signs[elem];
  }
  return elem;
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vu1a3jk/)